# Data is shown multiple times when sorted in views

Tags: views, 8

I'm using the module BibCite that provides a content type for managing bibliography. I want to show a list of all publications with Views. I'm using the fields mode and the citation field. The citation field is created by a BibCite engine that merges fields like author, title, publication year, etc. into one field. The problem is, when I want to sort them by author each publication is shown as many times as the number of authors it has. So a publication with with three authors is shown three times. I already tried the distinct query option and many variations of the aggregation option, but either too much is sorted out or there is an SQL error. How can I sort all publications by the last name of the first author?

EDIT: When I output only the author field it is a merged prename+name field. So maybe it is not even possible to sort by last name?

This is the SQL request:

```
SELECT bibcite_reference.langcode AS bibcite_reference_langcode, bibcite_reference.bibcite_year AS bibcite_reference_bibcite_year, bibcite_reference__author.author_target_id AS bibcite_reference__author_author_target_id, bibcite_reference.id AS id
FROM
{bibcite_reference} bibcite_reference
LEFT JOIN {bibcite_reference__field_dia_autor} bibcite_reference__field_dia_autor ON bibcite_reference.id = bibcite_reference__field_dia_autor.entity_id AND bibcite_reference__field_dia_autor.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {bibcite_reference__author} bibcite_reference__author ON bibcite_reference.id = bibcite_reference__author.entity_id AND bibcite_reference__author.deleted = '0'
WHERE (bibcite_reference__field_dia_autor.field_dia_autor_target_id = 'de')
ORDER BY bibcite_reference_bibcite_year DESC, bibcite_reference__author_author_target_id ASC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Under "Datenbankabfrageeinstellungen" in the right column, have you already selected to only have "distinct"/eindeutig or whatever is called results?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I tried, but no effect.

Comment: This info needs to be in your question then. But yeah, sounds like a bug. You already created an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/bibcite/issues/3201861), okay.

Comment: I posted it on almost every platform I know, but nobody has a solution :(